# How to populate value based on the value entered in DateInput in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently developing a Shiny App. Here, when I select a value from **selectizeInput()** and enter a date, then the date entered should be populated in the another **dataInput()**. For example if I selected "M" and if I entered a date, then the same date should be displayed in other **dateInput()**. I tried it using **observeEvent()**. But it did not work.

Here is the code used:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput('role', 'Select the Role',
                   choices = c('VP','M','AC','C'),options = list(
                     placeholder = "Please select your Role",
                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
    dateInput('cus', label ='Enter Current role start date',value = "",format = "mm/dd/yy"),
    dateInput('m', label ='Enter M date',value = "",format = "mm/dd/yy")

  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    observeEvent(input$role == "M",{
      updateDateInput(session, "m", value = (input$cus) )
    })
  }
)
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use uiOutput, instead of using the updateDateInput function.

```
   shinyApp(
   ui = fluidPage(
   selectizeInput('role', 'Select the Role',
                   choices = c('VP','M','AC','C'),options = list(
                     placeholder = "Please select your Role",
                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
    dateInput('cus', label ='Enter Current role start date',value = "",format = "mm/dd/yy"),
    uiOutput('m')
  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {


    output$m <- renderUI({
      value <- ""
      if(input$role == 'M') {
      value <- input$cus
      }  
      dateInput('m', label ='Enter M date',value = value,format = "mm/dd/yy" )
    })
    })

)
```

**This is the version which uses updateDateInput**

You need to use observe instead of observeEvent, as you need to track those input values real time.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput('role', 'Select the Role',
                   choices = c('VP','M','AC','C'),options = list(
                     placeholder = "Please select your Role",
                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
    dateInput('cus', label ='Enter Current role start date',value = "",format = "mm/dd/yy"),
    dateInput('m', label ='Enter M date',value = "",format = "mm/dd/yy")

  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    observe(
      if(input$role == 'M' & !is.null(input$role) & !is.null(input$cus)) {
      updateDateInput(session, "m", value = (input$cus) )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Is it possible using UpdateDateInput()?

Comment: observeEvent(input$role,{
      if(input$role == "M"){
        value = input$cus
        updateDateInput(session,"m",value = value)
      }
    })       I tried using this. But it still doesn't work!!

Answer (score 1):

You just need change observe, so

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput('role', 'Select the Role',
                   choices = c('VP','M','AC','C'),options = list(
                     placeholder = "Please select your Role",
                     onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
    dateInput('cus', label ='Enter Current role start date',value = "",format = "mm/dd/yy"),
    dateInput('m', label ='Enter M date',value = "",format = "mm/dd/yy")

  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    observeEvent(c(input$cus, input$role), {
      if (input$role == "M")
        updateDateInput(session, "m", value = (input$cus))
    })
  }
)
```

If you need to clear second date input in other cases, you can add `else` and update value to NA